# Running fifo pipe from single terminal

Tags: fork, exec

I was wondering if there is anyway to run two programs using named pipe i.e. fifo, by executing only one program. For example, solution mentioned here [Sending strings between two pipes][1] can it be ran using one terminal only? Is there anyway to call writer.c from reader.c and run the whole program just by running reader.c

EDIT: I removed my code because it had a lot of problems. I was using many functions without having any knowledge about them.

CLOSED.

Comment: One program or one process? You could one one program that uses `fork()` to split into a writer and reader process.

Comment: Your title says a single terminal? You know that you can run multiple programs from a single terminal, don't you? Run the first program in the background, then start the second one.

Comment: how can I run one program in background? From above example, how can I run writer.c just by typing ./reader.c in one terminal

Comment: You use `&` to run a program in the background: `writer &`

Comment: In my case, Imagine user doesn't know writer.c exists. So he will just run reader.c program,

Comment: If you want to use pipes,  you need two processes or threads. There's no need for multiple programs, and normal programs usually only deal with just one terminal.

Comment: I have two programs, one reader.c and writer.py, I want to run python program from C, just by using one terminal.

Comment: So what's the problem? Just fork a child process to run one of them.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: how by running one of them, second file will be executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the popen() function to run writer.py from inside your reader program:

https://linux.die.net/man/3/popen

The popen function returns a FILE * which you can then use with any C buffered I/O function.  Eg:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    FILE *fp;
    if((fp = popen("/path/to/writer.py", "r")) == NULL) {
        // handle error in some way
        perror("popen");
        exit(1);
    }

    size_t numbytes;
    char buffer[255];

    // Here we read the output from the writer.py and rewrite it to 
    // stdout.  The result should look the same as if you ran writer.py
    // by itself.. not very useful.  But you would replace this with code
    // that does something useful with the data from writer.py

    while((numbytes = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), fp)) > 0) {
        fwrite(buffer, 1, numbytes, stdout);
        // should check for error here
    }

    pclose(fp);
    exit(0);
}
```

PS: I did not compile or run this program, it is just an example to give you the idea... But it should work.  Also.. I notice you say writer.c in one place and writer.py in another.  It does not matter what language writer is written in.  As long as the program pathname you pass to popen() results in output being written to stdout, it will work.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have edited my post. Please let me know, how I can use your popen solution in my code

Comment: I don't understand where you are trying to execute your writer program in the code you posted???  You don't need a fifo, just a ordinary pipe which popen will give you (popen() actually calls system calls (functions) pipe() and fork() as well as fdopen() to do all the work.. so you don't have to figure all that out for yourself.  Use popen() as I showed you.)

Comment: I am required to use fifo. Is there anyway to use fifo pipe and run writer.py from C?

Comment: I see, well.. popen is easier, but since you are doing your homework.. or we are doing it.. look in the textbook.  Surely the prof didn't force you do use a solution that wasn't taught?  But yes if you have one program that creates and reads from a fifo and another that opens and writes to that fifo, you can just use fork(), then in the child process use exec() to run your writer program.  There are plenty of fork/exec examples on the internet just google and tons will come up.

Comment: Ok now looking at your edited question.  You need to understand that exec() does not create a new process.. it REPLACES the currently running program with a new one in the same process.  So you need to fork() first.  This results in two copies of your reader.  Now if fork() returns 0, you are in the child.. so `if(fork()==0) { exec(...); }` this causes your writer to start running while your reader continues.  Now, in the code for your writer, you must open the fifo `q1` that you created in the reader, but in "w" mode.. and write your data to it.  Now you can read from q1 in reader.  Got it?

Comment: I have edited my post again. I am able to run python program from C but not able to send any values to python program

Comment: First, use mkfifo BEFORE you fork, so that it will exist before either program needs it.  Second, NO code after exec will do anything.  If fork returns 0 you are in the child, and you Havel called exec which means the child is now running your python program.  So really the only thing you do if fork returns 0 is exec.  Take the part where you open the fifo for reading and move that to the bottom.. to where it will execute if fork returns > 0.

Comment: With your help, I was able to fix a lot of things of my program. But there is still one small problem. I have posted my output to show you whats wrong

Comment: You keep calling fork() over and over again.. each time you start another process.  Do like this:  First, create `mkfifo()` (q1), next `int pid = fork();  if(pid < 0) { perror("fork"); } else { if(pid==0) { exec() } else { fopen("./q1", "r") etc etc }`.  What are you trying to do with q2??  Since you are only communicating in one direction you only need one fifo.  If you want to communicate in both directions, that's a lot harder.

Comment: I am writing and reading from two different files. My code works fine if I use two terminals but it doesn't work when I only use one terminal

Comment: Please describe exactly what your program(s) are supposed to do.  Exactly.

Comment: My program opens the queue write strings to python program and then closes the queue. After that it opens a queue again read strings from python program then closes the queue